# Get users count on the basis of a another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in a problem explained below:

```
id | user_id | admin
1  |    1    |   2
2  |    1    |   5
3  |    2    |   5
4  |    2    |   5
5  |    3    |   5
6  |    4    |   5
```

I need to write a query to get all the users who are associated with an admin id passed in `WHERE` clause `AND` has **more than one transactions**(can be with another admin).

```
If user_id is 5 then result should come

user_id
1
2
```

Have tried

```
SELECT 
 user_id ,
 COUNT(*) count
FROM 
 table
 WHERE admin = 5
GROUP BY
 user_id
Having
count > 1
```

but this above-mentioned query skips the user_id that has only one transaction with admin = 5 and has another row with another admin.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate on the `user_id` and assert that:

- The admin of interest (e.g. `5`) appears,
- Two or more admins of any type appear

```
SELECT user_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN admin = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(*) > 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you also help with another case? If we need to skip first matching entry then how can we update your query? [Demo](http://rextester.com/WTY6290) . `user_id = 3` has first entry with `admin = 5` and second with `admin = 4`(if we order by `id` column) so we shouldn't consider 3 in result set.. If we don't consider first entry and then apply our logic, what should be the updated query?

Comment: @SatishSaini Ask a new question.  This would invalidate all the work everyone has done here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT user_id from `tablename` WHERE admin IN( SELECT admin FROM `tablename` GROUP BY admin HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Before giveing negative rating at-least give us a correct answer. I checked this query and its working fine. Its much better If you also provide a feedback thanks.....

Comment: I don't think so, there is no admin=5 criterion in your query, so cannot be fine. I agree with the downvoter.

Comment: @Shadow Please read Question properly  requirement is not only for admin 5 they actually need "I need to write a query to get all the users who are associated with an admin id passed in WHERE clause AND has more than one transactions(can be with another admin)."

Comment: I read the question properly :) you passed all admin ids that occured multiple times, not just a single one. The question is about specifying a single admin id (value 5 used as an example).

Answer (score 0):

In your query filter on `admin=5` and with a separate subquery on those users, who have more than 1 transactions. You need to have the count in a subquery because the `admin=5` criterion does not apply to the count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM yourTable
WHERE admin_id=5
    AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM yourTable GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user_id
FROM test_table1
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN admin = &n THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) > 0 
AND
COUNT(user_id) > 1;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to ask:

1. Show me all users who have more than one admin associated
2. Also allow me to identify which admin specifically is in question (in your example 5)

This would give you a list of every user (user id only)

```
SELECT  DISTINCT table.user_id
FROM    table
        JOIN (
            SELECT  user_id 
                    ,COUNT(DISTINCT admin_id) num_admins
            FROM    table
            GROUP BY user_id
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT admin_id) > 1
            ) multi_admin
            ON table.user_id = multi_admin.user_id
WHERE   admin = 5 -- if you want to look only at user_ids somehow associated with
```